# Finding a quadratic's preimage of an open interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$x\rightarrow x^2+2$

Find $f^{-1}((0,2))$

$f(x)=2+x^2$

So then $x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \in (0,2)$

So then I did $0<2+x^2<2$

and I got $-2<x^2<0$

So then I get the preimage is $(0,0)$

My second question is find the preimage for

$f^{-1}((-1,4))$

I did $x:\mathbb{R}:f(x)\in(-1,4)$

so then $-1<2+x^2<4$

I got $-3<x^2<2$ and then $(-\sqrt{2}.\sqrt{2})$ as the preimage.

I am not certain, if this is correct.

Comment: $x^2 \ge 0$ for all reals, and $x^2 > 0$ if $x\neq 0$. $f(x)$ is never less than $2$. So, what's the usual name for $(0,0)$, which here means "the set of all $x$ such that $0 < x < 0$"?

Comment: So for my first one the preimage then I think is $(0,infinity)$

Comment: @FernandoMartinez No,as $f(x) \geq 2$ $\forall x$.So there is no element in the fiber of $(0,2)$.[As you've also shown]

Comment: Your second answer is correct, by the way. Actually your first is too, assuming that $(0,0)$ means the (empty) open interval from $0$ to $0$. But there's a better name for that.

Comment: I see.  The better name is the null set.